# Is there a way to import a table of info from Excel to SQL database?

Tags: sql, excel, sql-insert

My employer wants me to create a database backup of contact information for parents (I work at a high school). I have my database with tables and all that sorted out. What I want to know is if there is a way to use INSERT to add all the info (or at least chunks of it) within a single statement?

I am aware of the import functionality that could do this automatically, however, my supervisor specifically wants me to do it manually from Excel to SQL "for training purposes"

I am not very keen on manually typing out 2643 INSERT statements so any help would be appreciated.

Note: I've truncated my example code as all 21 lines are not necessary for this question and I've changed confidential information.

```
USE [XSchoolContactInfoDB]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Parents] ([ParentId], [ParentTitle], [ParentName],[ParentSurname], [CellPhone], [LearnerID])
VALUES (<ParentId, smallint,>, 
        <ParentTitle, nvarchar(50),>,
        <ParentName, nvarchar(50),>, <ParentSurname, nvarchar(50),>,
        <CellPhone, nvarchar(50),>, <LearnerID], smallint>)
GO
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's all depend on which dbms you use.  With the information given, do you think anybody can help you?

Comment: There are many ways to import data from Excel, most products have bespoke options and dedicated ETL software options - all are product specific. It's not clear what you mean by "do it manually" - you typically import data into a staging table (Extract), cleanse the data (Transform) and then insert or update a target (Load).

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, those are the only instructions I was given. Supervisor didn't specify whether it has to be mysql, postgresql, etc. 
Supervisor personally prefers using SSMS 18 but it isn't a strict requirement.
By "do it manually" I meant that my supervisor wants to see me use some variation of INSERT or something similar to add all the data. No extra "fancy" software, wizards, external code, etc.

Comment: use CONCATENATE in Excel to create an INSERT for each row.  then paste all of the inserts into the database software (sql server?) and execute the statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you are being tasked to use excel to transpose a dump of data into insert statements. This can be done using simple formulas to generate a bunch of insert statements.

Simply insert a new column into the sheet and set the value to something like `='INSERT INTO dbo.Parents(ParentId,ParentTitle,ParentName,ParentSurname) VALUES('&A2&','''&A3''','''&A4'''...)'`

Then drag the formula down for all values in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're the first person that didn't make me feel like shit for asking a question. And your solution is brilliant! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Your supervisor's request is unclear, but my preferred technique would be to export the data from Excel to CSV, then use `BULK INSERT` (or `LOAD DATA ...INFILE` with MySQL) to read the file. Probably less error prone than creating a block of INSERT statements in Excel.

For example

```
USE ImportFromExcel;
GO
BULK INSERT Data_bi FROM 'C:\Temp\data.csv'
   WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#bulk-insert)

Comment: Yeah, my supervisor loves being unclear and difficult in a very petty way. 
Thank you so much for the input! That's super helpful!